# JSON Array Parsing Kafka

Tags: json, spring-kafka

I have the following setup:
A Rest endpoint to accept JSON POST request:
I am parsing the request and sending it as a String over Kafka.
But getting parsing errors
A Rest endpoint to accept JSON POST request:

```
[ { "Name": "Jack", "Id": "314", "Gender": "M" } , { "Name": "John", "Id": "451", "Gender": "M" }, { "Name": "Rita", "Id": "501", "Gender": "F" } ]
```

I am parsing the request as follows

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/record")
@ResponseBody
public String process(@RequestBody Map<String, Object>[] payload) throws 
Exception {
    String str = Arrays.toString(payload)
    KafkaProd.toTopic(str);
    System.out.println("Payload: " +str);
    return "Record Processed";
}


str = Arrays.toString(payload) is changing it into the following format
[ { Name = Jack , Id = 314, Gender = M } , { Name = John, Id = 451, 
Gender = M }, { Name = Rita, Id = 501, Gender = F } ]

When I'm trying to parse this string back into json array using json-s 
imple :

 JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(record.value());
 for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
 System.out.println("Json Objects : " 
 +jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).toString());
 }
```

I am getting JSON Parsing error, since the record.value() is not a valid json array

Option 1. How do I convert this to a valid json array?
 Option 2. How do I send the json array in a proper format through kafka?

Which of these options do I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `String str = Arrays.toString(payload)` use a Jackson `ObjectMapper` to convert the map to a String.

Comment: I wonder what is the point to convert an incoming JSON into `Map` and then back to JSON for sending to Kafka... What is the point to convert request `byte[]` to JSON at all since we can simply send that `byte[]` to Kafka?!

Comment: I was going to say the same, but I assumed this was just an example and his controller needs to examine the map contents.

Comment: I'm using byte[] bytes = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(payload).getBytes("utf-8")
Thanks Gary for pointing me in the right direction, Artem for the byte[] suggestion.